# Python docstring + Neo4J cypher query seems to cause regexp error

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher snippet like this:

```
where my_node.my_column =~ ("(?i).*\\." + {my_var})
```

The idea is to match a path-like string. For example, `my_column` could have a value of `db.schema.MY_TABLE` and I want to pass "My_TaBlE" in my Python cypher statement. This should match.

However, I am getting a Cypher error on that statement; Specifically, it does not like the final "." in the regexp. It is like I am not escaping it correctly.  The docs say Java regexp is used under the hood.

Right now I am using:

```
where my_node.my_column =~ ('(?i).*' + '.' + {table_name})
```

This seems to work, but I can't honestly say if the period is matching any character or the literal period character.

If it matters, my Cypher query is in a Python docstring.

How can I escape the period? Is there a better way to express what I am looking for?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? I'm not able to reproduce the Cypher. This works for me: `MATCH (a:Schema)
where a.my_column =~ ("(?i).*\\." + "MY_TABlE")
RETURN a` Can you share more of your code that shows how you are executing the query?

Comment: Without escaping the `.` it will match any characters

Comment: @WilliamLyon From the Neo4J web console it works for me too. So I think it is somehow related to my Python docstring. The code is torn up right now, I'll have to fabricate an example.

Answer (score 0):

In Python [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), the backslash ("\") character is used start an escape sequence. In particular, "\\" is the escape sequence for the backslash character itself.

So, in order to produce a string literal with 2 adjacent backslash characters, you actually need to use 4 adjacent backslash characters in your code. For example, your Python snippet should look like this:

```
where my_node.my_column =~ ("(?i).*\\\\." + {my_var})
```